# Hiding controls and show next control after click and increment a counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple controls in HTML. They consist of `li` and buttons and so on.

Initially I want to display first control, then after selection of the item, I get the value and then I get the other control which is button, after click, I get another button and so on.

I also have a span class that increments with the number of steps completed as follows:

```
<span id="step-count">1</span>

<ul id="user">
  <li class="mdl-menu__item">User 1</li>
  <li class="mdl-menu__item">User 2</li>
  <li class="mdl-menu__item">User 3</li>

</ul>

<!-- Step 2 -->
<button id="cost">Add cost</button>

<!-- Step 3 -->
<button id="work">Create a work</button>
```

Basically what I have done is the following:

```
$(function() {
  var count = 1;
  $('#cost').hide();
  $("#work").hide();
  $("#step-count").text(count);

  $("#user li").click(function() {
    console.log('I am in..');
    var $this = $(this);
    alert($this.text());
    $('#user').hide();
    count++;
    $('#cost').show();
    $("#step-count").text(count);
  });

  $("#cost").click(function() {
    console.log("Costing menu in..");

    $("#cost").hide();
    count++;
    $("#work").show();
    $("#step-count").text(count);
  });
});
```

Could someone advise me on a better way of doing this, suppose if I have 30 different controls, I cannot each time on click, hide the previous control and show the next one.

**Edited Part for li**

```
    <div id="steps">
        <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button user-menu mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect">
         Add User
        </button>

        <ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu js-user-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="user-menu">
            <li class="mdl-menu__item">User 1</li>
            <li class="mdl-menu__item">User 2</li>
            <li class="mdl-menu__item">User 3</li>
            <li class="mdl-menu__item">User 4</li>
            <li class="mdl-menu__item">User 5</li>
        </ul>
```

Basically, the above is showing a button, and when I click on the button, it gives me a drop down list where I can select an item. After I select an item, it disappears without showing the next component. Could you please help on this?

Comment: `Could someone advise me on a better way of doing this, suppose if I have 30 different controls` Better use a wizard plugin's like http://www.jquery-steps.com/ or any other similar. I think that's much better than reinventing the wheel

Comment: You can pass a parameter in the button click and manage the function in an if loop right. Anyway, you have a dynamic increasing value in the span.

Comment: Could please clarify further?

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose all your steps in a parent `<div id="steps">` and use the parent to select all its children, hide them at the beginning, and attach an event listener to them. You can move from one child to another by using `this` for the current child and `next()` for the next one. Check `next.length` to see if you reached the last step.

**EDIT** If you to call a different function for each step, create these functions with the same name with the step number at the end (example doJob1, doJob2, doJob3). This way you can call them using the `window` object.

```js
$(function() {
  var count = 1;
  var steps = $('#steps > *');
  steps.hide();
  $('#user').show();
  $("#step-count").text(count);

  steps.click(function() {
    window["doJob" + count]();
    var current = $(this);
    var next = current.next();
    if (next.length > 0) {
      current.hide();
      next.show();
      count++;
      $("#step-count").text(count);
    }
  });
});

function doJob1() {
  console.log("step 1");
}

function doJob2() {
  console.log("step 2");
}

function doJob3() {
  console.log("step 3");
}

function doJob4() {
  console.log("step 4");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="step-count">1</span>
<div id="steps">
  <button id="user" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button user-menu mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect">Add User</button>
  <ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu js-user-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="user-menu">
    <li class="mdl-menu__item">User 1</li>
    <li class="mdl-menu__item">User 2</li>
    <li class="mdl-menu__item">User 3</li>
    <li class="mdl-menu__item">User 4</li>
    <li class="mdl-menu__item">User 5</li>
  </ul>
  <!-- Step 2 -->
  <button id="cost">Add cost</button>
  <!-- Step 3 -->
  <button id="work">Create a work</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the awesome code. What if on each component click, I need to run a separate ajax function on each component click ?

Comment: Before the ul, I have a button as `<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button coordinator-menu mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect" id="user-menu">
                    Add User
                </button>`
It sets the li as button, and when clicked, it shows the li for me to select an item. But when applying your code, it does not display the components.

Comment: See my updated answer for how you can call different functions. As for your question about the `Add User` button, please edit your question and provide all the relevant code. Don't give us the code in bits and pieces and ask more questions. It's hard to answer in this fashion.

Comment: I have updated my question with the `li` part. Please, could you help ? That's the last part.

Comment: @RacilHilan i don't recommand your approch, especially about : $('#steps > *'); who grab any tag children of #step, but if you have decorator element such as div.form-control, they will be consider as "step". Also use window global variable to store function have risk of side effect with any other library or imported code.

Comment: I updated my answer to include your edit. Not much needs to be changed. Basically, you need to consider the `Add User` button and the list as two separate steps. So step 1 the `Add User` button, step 2 the list, step 3 the `Add cost` button, and step 4 the `Create a work` button. You need the keep the `id="user"` for the `Add User` button, and create a `doJob4()` function for the fourth step.

Comment: @Yanis-git Thanks for the comments, but this is just an answer, we don't need to spoon-feed or do the OP's job. If the code in question was different, I would've answered differently. The global functions will not have any conflict if you name them appropriately, and I don't think there is any commonly used library that uses the names `doJob1`, etc. However those functions can be easily added to an object and the same code will work by simply changing `window` to the name of the object.

Comment: Yes @RacilHilan is absolutely true, my advise is to help jones to pay attention to may side effect part this code. Probability of this is very small.

Answer (score 0):

You can have Common class on any step element. then when 1 is clicked, you can determine by some attribute what is current step, then determine who is next one.

Html : 
    1

```
<ul id="">
  <li class="mdl-menu__item step" attr-step="1">User 1</li>
  <li class="mdl-menu__item step" attr-step="1">User 2</li>
  <li class="mdl-menu__item step" attr-step="1">User 3</li>
</ul>

<!-- Step 2 -->
<button class="step" attr-step="2">
  Add cost
</button>

<!-- Step 3 -->
<button class="step" attr-step="3">
  Create a work
</button>


<button class="step" attr-step="4"> Create foo </button>
<button class="step" attr-step="5"> Create bar </button>
```

Javascript

```
$(function () {
        $counter = $('#step-count');
$allStep = $('.step');
var counter = 1;
$allStep.hide();
    $('.step[attr-step="'+counter+'"]').show();  

    $allStep.on('click',function() {
    //Get current step number.
        counter = parseInt($(this).attr('attr-step'));
        counter++;
  //Inc and update UI
  $counter.text(counter);
        $allStep.hide(); //Hide all
        $('.step[attr-step="'+counter+'"]').show(); // Display only current.  
    });
});
```

Attached Online sample : https://jsfiddle.net/j5ce2hah/16/

---- update with specific traitment on each step ----
You have now payloads object who return instance of jquery ajax object. and base on done promise, we update view and go to next step.

More info for jquery ajax request : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

```
 $(function () {
        var payloads = {
        getUser : function($step) {
                return $.getJSON( "/echo/json/",{'id': $step.attr('attr-user-id')}, function() {});      
      },
      getCost : function($step) {
                return $.getJSON( "/echo/json/", function() {});      
      },
      getWork : function($step) {
                return $.getJSON( "/echo/json/", function() {});      
      },
    };

        /**
        Init app
    **/
        $counter = $('#step-count');
    $allStep = $('.step');
    var counter = 1;
    $allStep.hide();
        $('.step[attr-step="'+counter+'"]').show();  
    //Step click handler
        $allStep.on('click',function() {
        //Get current step number.
            counter = parseInt($(this).attr('attr-step'));
            //Get whitch payload you want to run.
            var payload = $(this).attr('attr-payload');
            //When payload answer done,         
      payloads[payload]($(this)).done(function(data) {
        //Do what ever you want with answer.
        console.log(data);
        counter++;
        //Increment and update UI
        $counter.text(counter);
        $allStep.hide(); //Hide all
        $('.step[attr-step="'+counter+'"]').show(); // Display only current.  
      });
        });
 });
```

Online sample : https://jsfiddle.net/j5ce2hah/28/

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the awesome code. 

What if on each component click, I need to run a separate ajax function on each component click ?

Comment: i have updated my answer according to your new specification.

Comment: How can I get the value of the selected item in the `li` ? Please advise

Comment: is already provided, as you can see on 'getUser' function. You receive as parameter, current clicked jquery element. then i just take attribute 'attr-user-id' and provide this as data of my request.